# Setting Remote Desktop Services Profile and Home Directory paths Windows 2008

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, profile, drive, home-directory

I am trying to programmatically set users roaming profile path for remote desktop services (Terminal Services) in Windows 2008 R2 Acitve Directlry. I am able to do this in Windows 2003 without any issues using vbscript or powershell with similar code to that listed below.

```
objUser.TerminalServicesProfilePath = "\\testing\test\"& profilename
objUser.TerminalServicesHomeDirectory = \\testing\test\& username
objUser.TerminalServicesHomeDrive = "Y:"
objUser.AllowLogon = Enabled
objUser.SetInfo
```

I found that the AD object names have changed in 2008 R2 and have updated my code to reflect the changes like this.

```
objUser.msTSProfilePath = "\\testing\test\"& profilename
objUser.msTSHomeDirectory = "\\testing\test\"& username
objUser.msTSHomeDrive = "Y:"
objUser.AllowLogon = Enabled
objUser.SetInfo
```

The problem is that while this code updates the users AD object (which I verified using ADSIEDIT) the settings never shows up in Active Directory Users and Computers and it doesn't work when the user logges on to a remote desktop session.